# Populating firebase providerData via signInWithCustomToken

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm signing into firebase via signInWithCustomToken. Is there a way I can populate  firebase's providerData (i.e. user's provider-specific profile information) with this sign in method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The decoded token information is not available in the client, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246371/how-to-retrive-additional-fields-from-firebase-custom-token-into-userinfo/38252327#38252327. You can also decode it yourself in the client. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917020/where-to-find-auth-token-data-inside-firebase-objects/39918177#39918177

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't think this is a duplicate. The other questions are about custom claims encoded into the token. As far as I can tell, this is about populating the firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData fields, which do not come from custom claims.

Comment: Hmmm.... that might indeed be the case: reopened. Sorry about that.